# Line break in Netbeans PHP code template

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm using Netbeans 7.2.1

While using `cls` code template, it generate following code:

```
class ClassName {

    function __construct() {

    }

}
```

However I'm following zend coding standards so I need it as follow:

```
class ClassName
{

    function __construct()
    {

    }

}
```

I updated `cls code template` (Tools > Options > Code Template > PHP > cls) and under expended text, edited the template. However instead of line breaks, it is just giving spaces like

```
class ClassName {

    function __construct()     {

    }

}
```

How can I enforce line break?

Comment: [update your netbean its now 7.3](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Yes it is but we generally do not update with every new version. That's home PC and internet speed is very slow for that. Another reason, for weekend developers, upgrading IDE is low priority task unless it is broken. Do you mean netbeans 7.2.1 is now broken and updating netbeans will fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why but simple solution I found is to provide two line break. Similarly it provide line break automatically after `}`. So to achieve class structure as suggested by zend (second code block in question), we need to update `cls code template` as follow:

```
class ${ClassName}

{

    function ${__construct}()

    {
        ${selection}${cursor}
    }
}
```